# Where does UIImage operations run on watchOS extension

Tags: uiimage, watchkit

I am still new to watchOS and trying to understand how the architecture works. I have a watchOS 3 app that I have been working on that uses UIImage in my WatchKit extension. I do some operations with UIImage from assets in the extension. What I can't tell is where these UIImage manipulations happen, is it on the watchOS or on iOS? In some tutorials I read, it sounds like assets for extensions are stored in iOS and UIImage being form UIKit makes me believe its on iOS. Apple's WatchOS programmers guide has these 2 images:

[image: Relationship between the Watch app interface, the WatchKit extension, and the iOS app]
Apple says this image shows the relationship between the Watch app interface, the WatchKit extension, and the iOS app.

[image: Target structure in watchOS]
Apple says this image show the structure of a watchOS app. This seems to imply images are stored on watch.

I couldn't find any answers in the tutorials or programmers guide and the images used to describe how the watchOS works confused the situation even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WatchOS3 the watch extension code definitely runs on the Watch. This is what the first diagram is showing.

The watch app assets will also be on the watch - I *think* this is the "Storyboards and Resources" in the second diagram.

Your confusion probably arises from the fact this was different in WatchOS 1, when the extension did actually run on the phone. Maybe you were reading old tutorials?

Anyway I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful, do you have any documentation links to describe this in further detail?

Comment: The Apple [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW1) is pretty good IMHO, although you've probably read that already as it looks like that's where you got one of your diagrams.